# Having troubles w/functions and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm Using Visual studio (C++) in a class that I am taking, I've had to teach myself functions, and I've hit a small snag in the road that I'd appreciate some advice on.

What I'm having trouble with, is the part of the assignment that states i must

"Utilize a function that prints (not find) the largest/average/smallest commissions"

The way I read this, I'm assuming she only wants it to print, and not do calculations in the function.

A friend suggested I try void print(etc) However I'm unsure how to grab the calculation in main and give it to the function I'm trying to print, or am i going at it all wrong?

I've commented out the portion of code I was trying to function. You can also find it at the very bottom of the code.

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated, as most of what I've looked up haven't really dealt with this problem (that I've found)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#define TITLE "Alva's"
#define STANDARD 0.05
#define HYBRID   0.10
#define ELECTRIC 0.15
#define HOLD     50

void dashLine();
int getSalesId();
int runProgram();
char vehicleType();
double sellingPrice();
void print(double largeSmallAverage);

int main()
{
    int tot_count,
        id_num[HOLD], //* ID
        r_ay = 0,  //* array
        s_count, //*standard
        h_count, //*Hybrid
        e_count, //*electric
        hold_id, //*array Id
        compare, //*Pass
        change, //*change made when change has value
        yesno;
    double tot_standard,
        tot_hybrid,
        tot_electric,
        tot_price,
        price[HOLD],
        hold_price, //*Array hold
        comm_l,  //* Large
        comm_s,  //* Small
        hold_comm, //*Array hold
        avg_comm,
        tot_commission,
        commission[HOLD];
    char car[HOLD],
        temp_car;
    tot_count = 0;
    s_count = 0;
    h_count = 0;
    e_count = 0;
    tot_price = 0;
    tot_standard = 0;
    tot_hybrid = 0;
    tot_electric = 0;

    cout << "\n" << TITLE << " Commission Calculator";
    yesno = runProgram();
    while (yesno == 1)
    {
        dashLine();
        id_num[r_ay] = getSalesId();
        car[r_ay] = vehicleType();
        price[r_ay] = sellingPrice();
        tot_price += price[r_ay];

        switch (car[r_ay])
        {
        case 'S':
        case 's':
            commission[r_ay] = (price[r_ay] * STANDARD);
            tot_standard += commission[r_ay];
            s_count++;
            break;
        case 'H':
        case 'h':
            commission[r_ay] = (price[r_ay] * HYBRID);
            tot_hybrid += commission[r_ay];
            h_count++;
            break;
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
            commission[r_ay] = (price[r_ay] * ELECTRIC);
            tot_electric += commission[r_ay];
            e_count++;
            break;
        }
        cout << "\n The commission for this sale, for Employee ID: " << fixed << setprecision(0) << id_num[r_ay] << " is:$ " << fixed << setw(5) << setprecision(2) << commission[r_ay];
        cout << "\n";

        yesno = runProgram();

        r_ay++;
        if (r_ay >= HOLD)
            yesno = 0;
    }
    tot_count = (s_count + h_count + e_count);
    tot_commission = (tot_standard + tot_hybrid + tot_electric);
    {
        cout << "\n Number of standard vehicle commissions calculated =  " << fixed << setw(8) << setprecision(0) << s_count;
        cout << "\n Number of hybrid vehicle commissions calculated   =  " << fixed << setw(8) << h_count;
        cout << "\n Number of electric vehicle commissions calculated =  " << fixed << setw(8) << e_count;
        cout << "\n Number of vehicle commissions calculated          =  " << fixed << setw(8) << tot_count;
        cout << "\n Total Overall price calculated                    =$ " << fixed << setw(8) << setprecision(2) << tot_price;
        cout << "\n Total amount of standard vehicle commissions      =$ " << fixed << setw(8) << tot_standard;
        cout << "\n Total amount of hybrid vehicle commissions        =$ " << fixed << setw(8) << tot_hybrid;
        cout << "\n Total amount of electric vehicle commissions      =$ " << fixed << setw(8) << tot_electric;
        cout << "\n Total amount of all commissions paid out          =$ " << fixed << setw(8) << tot_commission;

        cout << "\n";
        cout << "\n " << "Sales ID   " << "Car type    " << "Selling price    " << "Commission    ";
        for (r_ay = 0; r_ay < tot_count; r_ay++)
        {

            cout << "\n " << fixed << id_num[r_ay] << "         " << setprecision(2) << car[r_ay] << "          " << setw(10) << price[r_ay] << "         " << setw(10) << commission[r_ay];
        }
        if (tot_count > 0)
        {
            avg_comm = (tot_commission / tot_count);
            comm_s = commission[0];
            comm_l = commission[0];
            for (r_ay = 1; r_ay < tot_count; r_ay++)
            {

                if (commission[r_ay] < comm_s)
                    comm_s = commission[r_ay];
                if (commission[r_ay] > comm_l)
                    comm_l = commission[r_ay];
            }
            void print(double largeSmallAverage);
            //{
            //  cout << "\n ";
            //  cout << "\n The smallest commission computed totals               =$ " << fixed << setw(10) << comm_s;
            //  cout << "\n The largest commission computed totals                =$ " << fixed << setw(10) << comm_l;
            //  cout << "\n Total average of commissions computed       =$ " << fixed << setw(10) << avg_comm;
            //}
        }

        cout << "\n";
        change = 1;
        compare = tot_count - 1;
        do
        {
            change = 0;
            for (r_ay = 0; r_ay < compare; r_ay++)
            {
                if (commission[r_ay] > commission[r_ay + 1])
                {
                    temp_car = car[r_ay];
                    hold_id = id_num[r_ay];
                    hold_price = price[r_ay];
                    hold_comm = commission[r_ay];
                    commission[r_ay] = commission[r_ay + 1];
                    commission[r_ay + 1] = hold_comm;
                    id_num[r_ay] = id_num[r_ay + 1];
                    id_num[r_ay + 1] = hold_id;
                    car[r_ay] = car[r_ay + 1];
                    car[r_ay + 1] = temp_car;
                    price[r_ay] = price[r_ay + 1];
                    price[r_ay + 1] = hold_price;
                    change = 1;
                }
            }
            compare--;
        } while ((compare > 0) && (change == 1));
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "\n " << "Sales ID   " << "Car type    " << "Selling price    " << "Commission    ";
        for (r_ay = 0; r_ay < tot_count; r_ay++)
        {

            cout << "\n " << fixed << id_num[r_ay] << "         " << setprecision(2) << car[r_ay] << "          " << setw(10) << price[r_ay] << "         " << setw(10) << commission[r_ay];
            cout << "\n ";
        }

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}

void dashLine()
{
    cout << "\n -----------------------------------";
}

int getSalesId()
{
    int id_num;
    cout << "\n Please enter Employee ID:                   ";
    cin >> id_num;
    while (id_num < 10000 || id_num > 99999)
    {
        cout << "\n Invalid Employee ID, Please enter a 5 digit ID ";
        cin >> id_num;
    }
    return id_num;
}

int runProgram()
{
    int rp_yesno;

    cout << "\n Is there a customer? 1 = yes, 0 = no ";
    cin >> rp_yesno;
    while ((rp_yesno != 1) && (rp_yesno != 0))
    {
        cout << "\n Invalid Entry Please enter 1/0 ";
        cout << "\n Is there a customer? 1 = yes 0 = no ";
        cin >> rp_yesno;
    }
    return rp_yesno;
}

char vehicleType()

{
    char car;

    cout << "\n Please enter type of vehicle sold";
    cout << "\n (S=standard, H=hybrid, E=electric):         ";
    cin >> car;
    while (!((car == 'S') || (car == 's') || (car == 'h') || (car == 'H') || (car == 'E') || (car == 'e')))
    {
        cout << "\n Invalid input Please enter S/E/H ";
        cin >> car;
    }
    return car;
}

double sellingPrice()

{
    double price;

    cout << "\n Please enter the selling price of the car:$ " << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cin >> price;
    while (price < 1)
    {
        cout << "\n Invalid entry, Please enter an amount greater than 0 ";
        cin >> price;
    }
    return price;
}

void print(double largeSmallAverage)
{
    double comm_s,
        comm_l,
        avg_comm;
    {
        cout << "\n ";
        cout << "\n The smallest commission computed totals               =$ " << fixed << setw(10) << comm_s;
        cout << "\n The largest commission computed totals                =$ " << fixed << setw(10) << comm_l;
        cout << "\n Total average of commissions computed       =$ " << fixed << setw(10) << avg_comm;
    }
}
```

Comment: please format your code. this is unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have a function called `print` that takes has three `double` parameters: `void print(double small, double large, double average);`.

Then later on you would call it with `print(comm_s, comm_l, avg_comm);`.

You need to change the definition of `print`:

```
void print(double small, double large, double average)
{
    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n The smallest commission computed totals               =$ " << fixed << setw(10) << small;
    cout << "\n The largest commission computed totals                =$ " << fixed << setw(10) << large;
    cout << "\n Total average of commissions computed       =$ " << fixed << setw(10) << average;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see where I messed up, then. Thanks for the example using my code. I understand how it's supposed to be, I've changed my code and haven't hit any snags. Thank you for your time and help!